# When to return task over using async

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am abit confused when it comes to how a method should look like when dealing with async / task.

From my understanding, a method that just creates a new task doesnt need to be async since this would produce overhead as it wraps the hole thing in a new task.

So this:

```
async Task _doStuff()
{
    await Task.Run(()=> _stuff());
}
```

Is better this way:

```
Task _doStuff()
{
    return Task.Run(()=> _stuff());
}
```

However, it gets a bit more complicated, if there are some preconditionchecks
Which way is better then?

```
async Task _doStuff()
{
    if(stuffWasDone)
        return;
    await Task.Run(()=> _stuff());
}
```

or

```
Task _doStuff()
{
    if(stuffWasDone)
        return Task.Run(()=> {}); // this could be a static-readonly in some helper like AsyncHelper.Empty(); as there is no FromResult for Task.

    return Task.Run(()=> _stuff());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have  to use `Task.Run` in order to generate a `Task`. A `Task` is a promise.
If a `Task` doesn't need to execute, don't create one. Using `Task.Run` has the overhead of invoking an empty lambda on a threadpool thread, you don't need that. Simply returning should suffice.

You may also use `Task.FromResult` if no `Task` is actually needed:

```
Task DoStuffAsync()
{
    if(stuffWasDone)
    {
       return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    return Task.Run(() => _stuff());
}
```

If you don't want to re-generate the `Task` over again, you can simply put it in a local variable:

```
private static Task _emptyTask = Task.FromResult(0);
```

As for your first example of `await` vs `return await`, you cannot say one is "better" then the other, as they serve different purposes. The former will asynchronously wait for the `Task` to complete before returning while the latter will return a hot task to the caller. This will matter in regards of exception handling. More so, if you're not going to be consuming the result of the task afterwards, using `await` will incur in a redundant generation of a state machine.

As another side note, [wrapping synchronous methods in asynchronous wrappers is bad practice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). Let the end user explicitly call `Task.Run` instead, don't fool them with async behavior.

Comment: @CSharpie What do you by mean *"simple return doesn't work"*? `Task.FromResult` isn't a simple `return` statement.

Comment: @PatrickHofman You should never return `null` from a method returning `Task`. Instead, return a completed task, faulted task, cancelled task or just throw the exception. But remember no null.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Can you explain why?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Because a `Task` is a promise which acts as a contract with calling code. A `Task` returning null is unexpected behavior. Look throughout BCL async API's, you always get some form of a `Task` which describes the behavior of what occured inside the `Task`. `null` will surprise callers and will result in undefined behavior most of the time.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Because who cares about checking `null` for `Task` returned from a method? You can't await it(NRE will be thrown), or calling `Wait` will also result in NRE. NRE gives no information about what is null. Makes debugging worse.